# Mat Sort header does not sort data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have exhausted all examples, documentation and so on. I've used angular tables for three years now and even within the app I have this issue, I have other tables that have no issue working with sort. I kept comparing them but I can't figure out what the difference between the two are.

```
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IOrder>;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild('mainTable', { static: false }) table: MatTable<IOrder>;
```

then, when the data arrives from store/http call and so on:

```
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(orders);
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.ref.detectChanges();
          this.table.renderRows();
```

On the frontend:

```
<table
        matSort
        class="table"
        mat-table
        multiTemplateDataRows
        [dataSource]="dataSource"
        #mainTable
      >
```

and the definitions:

```
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="activeColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr
          mat-row
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: activeColumns; let i = index"
        ></tr>
```

and then an example of actual row:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="UPRN">
          <th
            class="table-header"
            mat-header-cell
            *matHeaderCellDef
            mat-sort-header="UPRN"
          >
            UPRN
          </th>
          <td class="table-cell" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
            {{ row.site.UPRN }}
          </td>
        </ng-container>
```

I've had one for createdAt as well which is identical.

Everything seems to be defined properly and there's no errors anywhere.

If I log on the console the mat sort, I can see all the right rows/columns in the 'Entries'.

Comment: Can you create `stackblitz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually worked was provindg a function with a switchcase as the value for dataSource.sortingDataAccessor property, like this:

```
          this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
            switch (property) {
              case 'UPRN':
                return item.site.UPRN;
              case 'Status':
                return item.status;

              case 'Updated at': {
                return item.updatedAt;
              }
              case 'Updated By': {
                return item.updatedByFriendly;
              }
              case 'Created by': {
                return item.createdByFriendly;
              }
              default: {
                return item[property];
              }
            }
          };
```

Intellisense helps out with available properties as well. The case strings must be identical to what you've provided as column definitions.

Answer (score 0):

If everything imported right,
I think it isn't working because it is looking for `row.UPRN` instead of `row.site.UPRN` because you defined `mat-sort-header="UPRN"`
Please try to do custom sort logic something like this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1urgk9

I hope this helps you solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know if this just breaks the whole app or sorting won't work for that? I have for example sort.status where the value is a string and the sort doesn't seem to work on any of those straightforward properties.

Will give this a shot though!

Comment: @MichaelB I think it doesn't break the app, just the sort will not work.

Comment: @MichaelB can you check the imports? Please make sure you are imported the `MatSortModule` into that module where your component imported and declared into `declarations`

Comment: the Angular Material models are all imported via a shared module into all modules and it works in another module that just shared the data like that.